# Web API Token authentication vs Custom token authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Very much new to Web API's. Trying to implement the `token` method the `Web API` uses to authenticate a user against database and use the `token` for all successive API calls. But i am finding it very difficult to follow the steps to do the same for `mysql DB` . I also feel it is a complex process for a simple login.

So my question is instead of using the `Web API token` method. Why not have a traditional Login function(`web api`) which checks the `userid/pwd` against `db userid/pwd` ? Which generates a token similar to `AuthenticationTicket` in `ApplicationOAuthProvider`, and send it as `response` to an ajax call and store in javascript `sessionStorage` for successive calls.

What is the difference in terms of security/general in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of thing needs to be considered while using a token for authentication. If you are using standard token implemention like `JWT`,  you will get all of these out of the box.

- Expiration Handling
- Tamper proof (Signed)
- Encrypted
- Replay Attack protection
- Claim based
- Decentralized

If you want to go with your custom token implementation, in that case you need to handle all of these on your own which can be time consuming and prone to vulnerability.

Comment: Any url available on how to setup token for mysql? Is EF mandatory?